# Odd and Even in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to draw a line with cylinders. The problem is that I need all the odd cylinders rotated of 90º.

I'm looking for a geometry nodes function like odd/even, but I can't find it.

Any idea how to do it?

[image]

My Geometry Nodes

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add these 3 nodes to your node tree:

[image]

The modulo 2 node generates a list of 0 1 0 1 0 1 ... for growing integers.

Comment: Thanks Chris, is exactly what i need :)